# Free DDNS service

Tags: networking, dynamic, dns, overriding, noip

I have got one firewall, with a public IP (dynamic) provided by my ISP.

As the IP is dynamic, I registered a domain in the service NO-IP as not to worry whether the IP changes anymore.

The problem:

Looks like my ISP is also giving a name for that IP, so when I resolve it (standard DNS configured, such 8.8.8.8) it would resolve the name in favour of my ISP.

The key point:

¿Is there any way to "OVERRIDE" the name given by the ISP with the one registered in NO-IP, in order to ALWAYS resolve to the no-ip name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you did with NO-IP/DDNS, it will have no effect on [Reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). Reverse DNS is controlled by whoever "owns" the IP address, usually your ISP, so they would have to change the record according to your request (or sub-delegate it to your DNS servers) which they will almost certainly not do since you have dynamic IP address.

Comment: You are right it is up to my ISP, I'll have to work my issue out some other way. Thanks for your reply!